# How to use same data for attribute and variable constructor?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm creating a server using WCF, and to create the different endpoint adresses i'm using function attributes, like in this example:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ErrorClass))]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/endpoint/adress", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public async Task<Stream> EndpointFunction(Stream someContent)
{
    magic
}
```

Then, in a client library, we have the same data defined so that the url can be constructed dynamically, like this:

```
public const string ServerSettings = "/endpoint/adress/";
```

I would really love to not hardcode the endpoint adress in both those places. In c++, i would define a macro #ENDPOINTADRESS "/endpoint/Adress" and use it in both places, but macros do not exist in C#. Is there any way to avoid this code duplication?

Comment: @Viru Not an option since the values of attributes are compiled into the assembly, and therefore not 'settable' at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately attributes, and their values, are compiled into the assembly. Therefor it is not possible to set their value at run-time.

However, if you, from the client-side, can reference the assembly where you define the server class you can use reflection on the client-side to retrieve the attribute value. Something like this:

```
// TODO: Add all kinds of safety checks
var mi = typeof(ServerImplementationClass).GetMethod("EndpointFunction");
var atts = mi.GetCustomAttributes(false);
var wi = atts.OfType<WebInvokeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
var uri = wi.UriTemplate;    // Yields: "/endpoint/adress"
```

Comment: That's very cool, but that would require the client side project to include the interface or even implementation class of the server side, which is more shared that i would like. Also, reflection might be a bit expensive, especialy in Unity3D running on Android/iOS, which is what our client does... I might go with this solution if i don't find another way, thanks again :)

Comment: The reflection would only have to be done once, at start-up. And... you can use a little hack with linked files, and partial classes, to keep the actual implementation from leaking to the client project.

Comment: Thank you for tour help @maarten. What kind of security checks did you have in mind?

Comment: @Cousken If you mean the safety checks in regards to the answer: I would add various null checks to prevents null-reference-exceptions.